# find difference and similarities between two text files using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I have two files:

file 1

```
1
2
34:rt
4
```

file 2

```
1
2
34:rt
7
```

I want to display rows that are in file 2 but not in file 1, vice versa, and the same values in both text files. So file the expected result should look like:

```
1 in both
2 in both
34:rt in both
4 in file 1
7 in file 2
```

This is what I have so far but I am not sure if this is the right structure:

```
 awk '    
    FNR == NR {      
        a[$0]++;
        next;           
    }    

    !($0 in a) {                          
        // print not in file 1
    }



    ($0 in a) {                         

        for (i = 0; i <= NR; i++) {
            if (a[i] == $0) {
                // print same in both
            } 
        }

        delete a[$0]  # deletes entries which are processed
    }

    END {                               
        for (rest in a) {                
            // print not in file 2
        }
    }' $PWD/file1 $PWD/file2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `comm`?

Comment: @choroba Didn't even know what that was but I will look it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is not relevant then you can do:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { a[$0]++; next }
{
    print $0, ($0 in a ? "in both" : "in file2");
    delete a[$0]
}
END {
    for(x in a) print x, "in file1"
}' file1 file2
1 in both
2 in both
34:rt in both
7 in file2
4 in file1
```

Or using `comm` as suggested by [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413846/find-difference-and-similarities-between-two-text-files-using-awk/24414214#comment37768217_24413846) in comments:

```
comm --output-delimiter="|" file1 file2 | 
awk -F'|' '{print (NF==3 ? $NF " in both" : NF==2 ? $NF "in file2" : $NF " in file1")}'
1 in both
2 in both
34:rt in both
4 in file1
7 in file2
```